# GMS Error during build while using proguard

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-proguard

When I try to build my project while using proguard I get the following error at pre verifying.

```
Preverifying...
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmz]
  Method      = [zza(Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmh;Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzne;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzgf;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmy;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmz]
  Method      = [zza(Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmh;Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzne;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzgf;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmy;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes))
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmk] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes)
```

I have added the following in the proguard, there are other rules also for other libraries.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**
```

My gradle.build has following libraries

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    //ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$rootProject.workManagerVersion"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$rootProject.timberVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.interceptorVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rx2AndroidVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rx2AndroidVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$rootProject.billingVersion"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:$rootProject.facebookAds"
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$rootProject.gPlacesVersion"){
        exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.gLocationVersion") {
        exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.firebaseCore"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
//    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$rootProject.firebaseConfig"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$rootProject.firebasePerf"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'
```

As per Google Play Services setup site, there is no need to add anything to proguard, when I remove the gms rules from proguard a get long list of warning like these

```
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzb
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzc
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaf
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaf$zza
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaf$zza
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced method 'void disconnect()' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapu
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced method 'boolean isConnected()' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapu
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapt$zza: can't find referenced method 'boolean isConnecting()' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzapu
```

The list of warning continues. I can add the rest of the proguard rules if required.
The Google Play service I'm using is 4.1.0 and my Firebase libraries are up-to-date, according to the Firebase site. using version 15.0.1 (newest) for Google play Google Play locations and locations

[Proguard Output](https://pastebin.com/2UJM4hgh)

Comment: could you add the `output` of ProGuard, when running without these `dontwarn` rules?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I get the warning errors as I as mentioned in the question.

Comment: these barely matter, while the output does ...at least the part, where it complains.

Comment: @MartinZeitler sorry, i am a bit new to proguard, how do i get the output?

Comment: it's part of the regular build logs - and it ordinary tells quite explicitly, what to do (which rules to define)... adding the `-verbose` option also might help, to understand what is going on there.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have uploaded the log here https://pastebin.com/2UJM4hgh

Comment: Could you list the versions for all the com.google.android.gms and com.google.firebase libs in your dependency tree?  ./gradlew :app:dependencies

Comment: @PaulR here is the dependency tree for gms and firebase libraries https://pastebin.com/buSBLtGQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing lots of rules there, beside the ones for `com.google.android.gms.internal.*` (which means: `Google Services`). the [manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting) explains all of these suggestions; while I can nevertheless leave an example, for that one class:

```
-verbose
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** {com.google.android.gms.internal.** initialize(android.content.Context);}
# -dontnote com.google.android.gms.internal.**
# -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.**
```

just commented out `dontnote` and `dontwarn`, because it's easier to be notified of everything, while developing the rule-set. adding the modifier `includedescriptorclasses` should at least reduce the complains by a few lines, already - while you have to define rules, until there are no more complaints left. it's a lengthy and bothersome process, without any default recipe - and it is quite impossible to provide reliable rules, while not being able to use the method of `trial & error`.